# How do I change my portrait photo on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

Before the UI change in Tumblr, the option to change the profile picture could be found in the same place where one customizes their blog.

[image: The option is not there anymore]

Where has the option moved to now ? I tried looking in the preferences and it is not there either.

[image: Tumblr Preferences]

Which only takes me to ways to change my email address and password.

So how do I change my photo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to see this under the Settings page of your tumblelog.

1. From the Dashboard, click on the name of your tumblelog
2. Click **Blog Settings** on the sidebar to the right

This page will allow you to upload the Portrait Photo.

The URL of the page will look something like this:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/tumblelog/[example]/settings
```

Which gets redirected to this:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/blog/[example]/settings
```